# SyncStateNotFoundError when syncing with messages on MSGraph using delta

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am using MSGraph delta queries for downloading messages only.
Recently, we encountered the following error while trying to sync:

```
The sync state generation is not found; generation=3426;[highest=3424][3424][3422][3423].
```

I found other questions on StackOverflow, where the generation provided is older than the one on the server, but if I'm not reading the error incorrectly, it seems that the server is saying that I am sending it a delta token from the future.

Why does this happen and what is a good strategy to recover in this position?